# Outputting all prime numbers from 0-10000 with arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, primes

I have a homework task to output all the prime numbers from 0-10000 in C#, but must utilise arrays in my solution

My code is:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Int32[] numbers = new int[10000];

    for (int i = 3; 1 < 10000; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = i;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
    {
        if (numbers[j] != 0)
        {
            for (int k = 2; (k * j) < 10000; k++)
            {
                numbers[k * j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; l < 10000; l++)
    {
        if (numbers[l] != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[l]);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I keep receiving the error :

> main.cs(17,5): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
>       Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>         at MainClass.Main () [0x00012] in <9e6bcdf6e2a44b4eb679270e1ffe39ca>:0 
>       [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 
>       was outside the bounds of the array.
>         at MainClass.Main () [0x00012] in <9e6bcdf6e2a44b4eb679270e1ffe39ca>:0`

(Line 17 referring to `for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)`)

Comment: `int y = 0; l < 10000; l++` should probably be `int l = 0; l < 10000; l++`

Comment: The perils of copying and pasting code without proof-reading

Comment: also `int i = 3; 1 < 10000; i++` should be `int i = 3; i < 10000; i++`

Comment: 'for (int y = 0; l < 10000; l++)' you have a error here too, l is not even defined

Comment: `for (int i = 3; 1 < 10000; i++)` is an infinite loop.  Everything after is unreachable and very quickly you will get an index out of range exception because `numbers[i] = i;` is only `10000` deep

Comment: The y part has already been changed, didn't realise the i/1 part though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix you `for` loops, so it ends up like this:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 10000; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = i;
}

for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
{
    if (numbers[j] != 0)
    {
        for (int k = 2; (k * j) < 10000; k++)
        {
            numbers[k * j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

for (int l = 0; l < 10000; l++)
{
    if (numbers[l] != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numbers[l]);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, your first loop will be infinite because of the validation `1 < 10000` and your third loop will throw an error

**UPDATE**

After reading @"Sani Singh Huttunen" comment I changed the first loop to start with `2` so it would count that number as prime, and that would remove `4` from the result list since that's not a prime number.

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jspVTx) is a working example

Comment: This will still give an index out of range exception, when j == 10,000 and k == 10000, it will be trying to assign `numbers[10000 * 10000] = 0`

Comment: But there's a validation of `(k * j) < 10000` in the loop

Comment: This will though not get all prime numbers. `2` is missing and `4` it says is prime which it isn't. Easily fixed though by `for (int i = 2; i < 10000; i++)` or declaring `numbers[2] = 2;`.

Answer (score 2):

The first loop in your code:

```
for (int i = 3; 1 < 10000; i++)
```

Is essentially an infinite loop, 1 will *always* be less than 10,000 and thus will never exit.  Everything after this loop is now unreachable.

You get your error because after 10,000 loops you will still try to do this:

```
numbers[i] = i;
```

And `i` will be greater than 9999 which will cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`

After you fix this you will find you have more issues, but since this is homework you will need to try to fix those yourself

Comment: There are other places that will throw that exception after the first one is fixed.

Comment: @RonBeyer There are far too many other problems after this is fixed.  The question only asks how to fix the errors they are receiving, new problems deserve new questions.  Plus, this is homework and I am not doing _all_ the work for them